# How do I get Active Directory's LDAP server url using windows API?

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap

I've been looking for a way to get Active Directory's LDAP server url from code running as domain user. The code needs to work correctly in situation with [disjoint namespace](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731125%28WS.10%29.aspx), if possible. It's unmanaged code so any .NET solutions are not an option unfortunately.

For some reason serverless binding doesn't seem to be working in this case with ADO query returning unhelpful `One or more errors occurred during processing of command` error when using `LDAP://DC=mycompany,DC=local` (that's the value of the `defaultNamingContext` attribute of `rootDSE` object).

Using the `LOGONSERVER` and `USERDNSDOMAIN` environment variables doesn't appear to be an option either because the code also needs to be able to run under the SYSTEM account and there are no such variables there.

Any ideas or hints or specific RTFM advice will be much appreciated.

Update: The `DNSHostName` attribute of `rootDSE` seems to be what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this **Visual Basic Script** (VBS). Save the code as `.vbs` file and use ANSI charset. This script is old, but this can guide you to a better solution.

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set cmd= CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject;"
cn.open
cmd.ActiveConnection = cn

' Root DSE required to get the default configuration naming context to
' be used as the root of the seach
set objRootDSE = getobject("LDAP://RootDSE")
' Construct the LDAP query that will find all the domain controllers
' in the domain
ldapQuery = "<LDAP://" & objRootDSE.Get("ConfigurationNamingContext") & _
    ">;((objectClass=nTDSDSA));ADsPath;subtree"

cmd.CommandText = ldapQuery
cmd.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
Set rs = cmd.Execute

do while rs.EOF <> True and rs.BOF <> True
    ' Bind to the domain controller computer object
    ' (This is the parent object of the result from the query)
    set objDC = getobject(getobject(rs(0)).Parent)

    wscript.echo objDC.dNSHostName
        rs.MoveNext
Loop

cn.close
```

Answer (score 0):

The DNSHostName attribute of rootDSE seems to be what I need.